# How can you reach the Code of Conduct page other than the announcement banner on top?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

The new Code of Conduct page can be visited by clicking the link in the black announcement banner on top. But once it's closed, I couldn't find a link to it anywhere else on the page.

Is there a link already that I haven't noticed? If not, shouldn't it be directly accessible?

**PS** It's not for me to read it again and again, nor is it to smack it on other users.

So, why then?

Cos I believe, Code of Conduct as described in the page is very important for the SO/SE community and should reach as many users as possible. I myself have faced unpleasant situations where I'm already helpless with some issue cos I'm new to it and certain users make the situation more hopeless because it's trivial to them (by not providing a solution and instead making an over-smart statement).

It's possible that due to the natural tendency of closing pop-ups, banners, notifications, users might directly close the announcement banner once the page loads. So is that it? Well on certain pages you have the blog link on the right-hand side that's sticky, this could be enough. I'm not aware of how long the blog link would remain, I'd still hope there is a permanent link to the Code of Conduct page from all pages, maybe in the footer or so.

*I should have rather framed the title as **"Shouldn't the Code of Conduct page be more easily accessible and linked from every page on SO?"***

Comment: I would like to just point out to you that, the main intention of my question was to ask if there is a way to reach the Code of Conduct page from the general navigation of the site. :)

Comment: It is a pretty weird requirement.  You read it once, grok what it tells you and try to live up to its demands.  If you need it to smack users over the head with in a comment, please don't.

Comment: @HansPassant Well I guess I didn't express myself completely/clearly. I've made an edit. Hope my question makes more sense now.

Comment: Do you guys think the CoC will change anything? I mean: which kind of questions/answers/comments have been tolerated before which will no longer be tolerated? Which kind of questions/answers/comments have not been tolerated before which will be tolerated now? Any example? I'm not against the CoC, I just think its impact can be overestimated easily. I believe: in any community there will be some amount of conflict. This is unavoidable and not even a sign that anything is wrong. That's life. Let's just make the best of it.

Comment: @Michael that sounds like a whole other discussion topic, maybe you could start one?

Answer (score 20):

Apart from the temporary links in the announcement and the "hot link"/"blog" section on the right, there is a more lasting way to find it.

1. On the the top right, click the so called "burger menu" (the "three bars" button).
2. Choose "help".
3. Top of middle column: "Code of conduct."

It is the same "path" to find it on main StackOverflow and meta.

Answer (score 11):

**In answer to the second part of the question:**

> "Shouldn't the Code of Conduct page be more easily accessible and
>   linked from every page on SO?"

I agree with @NeilPatrao the Code of Conduct should be made easier to find.

At the moment you have to dig to find it (other than the featured blog links). As you can see from the other answers, you need to go to the `Help Center > Our Model > Code of Conduct`

***Suggestion:*** I think the Code of Conduct has equal importance to any of the other links in the `(?)` toolbar such as `Tour`, `About Us` and `Business`; so the link should probably live there.

Any user that wants to follow up or double check their conduct is reflecting "The Code" should be able to quickly and easily check it in this resource that was explicitly made for the purpose of keeping us accountable.

[image: Help Center Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

Here is the link

- https://stackoverflow.com/conduct
- https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/?cb=1

It is also available in [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

[image]

It is temporarily available on the home page of Meta Stack Overflow

[image]

It is temporarily available on the home page of Stack Overflow

[image]

Comment: Those 2 blog links won't be there forever.

Comment: Still, upvote for the top screenshot with free-hand circle.