# Magic link for Code of Conduct

Tags: feature-request, code-of-conduct, magic-links

I see [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) went live. I was thinking perhaps we should add a shorthand link in comments to already existing array of [shorthand links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) where `[conduct]` will expand to "[Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)". That could help educate people who ignore the banner (or when the banner goes away), and it could help cut arguments in comments short.

Relevant - *[How can you reach the Code of Conduct page other than the announcement banner on top?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372270/how-can-you-reach-the-code-of-conduct-page-other-than-the-announcement-banner-on/372272)*

Comment: The best way to cut arguments in the comments short is for one of the participants to stop commenting.

Comment: What about using the already existing [help/behavior]? There is a link to the Code of Conduct on that page.

Comment: I don't really see how posting a link to something you have to willingly read AND agree with will cut any argument short. It will likely just turn up the heat. "Have you read it yourself?", "Yeah I've read it, I don't know how it is relevant here", etc.

Comment: @AndréKool Sure, you can do that. `[conduct]` or even `[coc]` would be just a quicker shortcut to more precise location. I just want to get community's feedback on whether we would find this feature useful or not.

Comment: @AlexL There is already a magic link for the help center of `[help]` which is shorter/easier to type than `[conduct]`.

Comment: For those using my [ChatMoreMagicLinks](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ChatMoreMagicLinks.user.js) userscript for chat, this has already been [added](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/commit/cfd3f79d27a8c4868b03a29ce6a832561015641f).

Comment: As an alternative, there's `[conduct](/conduct)`. It is slightly longer, but it at least doesn't require the full link.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think this magic link is necessary. Instead of taking up moderator duty for posts/comments that violate the CoC, you should flag them. Moderators can take additional measures as they see fit, e.g. have a conversation with the user about their behaviour.

Comment: Curiously, due to an OP's phraseology in his/her title, I wanted to direct him/her to the Code of Conduct without burning up a lot of comment space to do so (you could flag the post and let the moderators do it, but what's the point of having the CoC in the [help] if they're the only people who should be dealing with it?}.  Considering your answer only focuses on comments and not the rest of any post, you may wish to reconsider it.  After all, SE is supposed to be a predominantly user-moderated site.